# React JS: adding key and value to a const

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update my "payload" object adding a key and value (codigoCompra: tmpCodigo), my code is this:

```
const onSubmit = (values) => {
console.log('valores enviados', values);

const min = 1;
const max = 100;
const tmpCodigo = Math.trunc(min + Math.random() * (max - min));

const payload = {
 ...values,
 //codigoCompra: parseInt(values.codigoCompra, 10),
 cantidadItemCompra: parseInt(values.cantidadItemCompra, 10),
 codigoProducto: parseInt(values.codigoProducto, 10),
 codigoCliente: parseInt(values.codigoCliente, 10),
 codigoCompra: tmpCodigo,
};

console.log({ values, payload });
```

after the last console.log the key "codigoCompra" wasn't added. My question is: how can I update payload adding codigoCompra and its value (tmpCodigo)?

All the best

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `payload` elsewhere in the code? The `const` variable cannot be modified after being declared. I tested it with ignoring the `value` variable, the payload contains `codigoCompra`. Can you provide the full `onSubmit` function and  a sample `value` input as well?